# Text won't stay fixed over text when resized larger

Tags: html, css

I've tried changing the pixels to percentages, I tried putting the image as a background image and it still didn't work. at this point I'm lost. Also I am using an animation I did forget to include, It is on the 'a' element with a scale of 1.1;

Preview - https://codepen.io/jontabshi/pen/oNgVaqZ

HTML

```
 <div class="button-contact">
        <a href="#" alt="contact">
        <img src="https://00.rc.xiniu.com/g1/M00/1E/4D/CgAGTF1BQzWALqT4AApMEzKQS6Y824.jpg" alt="contact button"/>
        <h2>What are you waiting for?</h2>
        <p>Many opportunities wait for you at Web Design and<br>Programming, get in touch now.</p>
        </a>
```

CSS

```
/* Layout */

.button-contact {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button-contact img:first-of-type {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.button-contact h2,.button-contact p,.button-contact #white-button {
    position: absolute;
}

.button-contact h2 {
    bottom: 140px;
    left: 360px;
}

.button-contact p {
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 363px;
}

#white-button {
    right: 350px;
    bottom: 125px;
}

/* Styles */

.button-contact img:first-of-type {
    filter: brightness(40%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(40%);
}

.button-contact h2 {
    font-family: Bebas, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 71px;
}

.button-contact p {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Please help. I'd appreciate it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out its just this

```
.button-contact{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:(picture width) px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a base for text to show upon. So specify **position: relative** to the button-contact div. Also, you need to auto calculate the font-size as per the width of the screen.

```css
.button-contact a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-contact {
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.button-contact img:first-of-type {
  max-width: 100%;
  filter: brightness(40%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(40%);
}

.button-contact h2,
.button-contact p {
  position: absolute;
}

.button-contact h2 {
  bottom: 140px;
  left: calc(100% - 72vw);
  font-family: Bebas, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 5vw;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.button-contact p {
  bottom: 80px;
  left: calc(100% - 71.5vw);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button-contact">
    <a href="#" alt="contact">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455459182396-ae46100617cb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="contact button">
      <h2>What are you waiting for?</h2>
      <p>Many opportunities wait for you at Web Design and<br>Programming, get in touch now.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this method yet it didn't work it didn't fix my solution of staying in the same position yet it made it even worse. Thank for helping tho. I appreciate it.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: the browser im using is chrome